# how to create flow chart of time stamped data using Python

Tags: r, python-3.x, data-visualization, visualization

I have a timestamped data similar to the table I have created below

| ID | year | feature1 | feature2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | A | 40 |
| 1 | 2016 | A | 50 |
| 1 | 2015 | B | 60 |

I want something similar in this zone, I have used powerpoint to create the following image but the original dataset has too many IDs and more features so creating flowchart for each ID is practically impossible
[image: For Instance]

So basically my goal is that I create function which accepts ID and creates flow chart.
I am unable to find library which can help me create this.
It would be great if answer is given for Python/R. Thank you.

Comment: It's really better if you can show what you've tried so far that you need help with. Without picking one of the two languages you've tagged, it's also pretty broad

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `mermaid` format:

```r
library(DiagrammeR)

mermaid("
graph LR
    A[Christmas] -->|Get money| B(Go shopping)
    B --> C{Let me think<br />feature 2}
    C -->|One| D[Laptop<br />feature 3]
    C -->|Two| E[iPhone]
    C -->|Three| F[fa:fa-car Car]
")
```

https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/edit